# Prisma Studio: The column `(not available)` does not exist in the current database

Tags: prisma

I got this error while working with Prisma, my solution is below.

I just want to post a solution, I don't have a question anymore. I need to keep typing this in order to meet Stack Overflow quality stnadards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that my schema and database weren't up to date.

I added a field to my model, but didn't push/migrate it to my actual db.

The solution was to push/migrate the new schema to the database

Comment: And don't forget to stop and restart the server to see the new model reflected!

Comment: I am getting this error though I've pushed/migrated my prisma schema and also restarted my app process but still the same error. It's throwing this error in vitest though and not in application